# Spring Cloud Sleuth stopped pushing X-B3-TraceId into MDC after spring-boot/spring cloud upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have upgraded my Spring boot dependencies from `2.1` to `2.4.5` and spring cloud to `2020.0.2`.
After this upgrade, my MDC context is not populated.

Any ideas of what should be done here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in spring cloud `2020.0.2` you have sleuth `3.x` and there is a migration guide telling about [some changes to MDC](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.0-Migration-Guide#x-b3--mdc-fields-names-are-no-longer-set)

Comment: I renamed the key and I still have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer depends on your use-case but as far as I remember, there was a change and the MDC context is cleaned-up after the span is finished.

This means that if you are in the scope of the Span (e.g.: controller method), you can see the Sleuth-related parts of the MDC but if you are outside of the scope of the span (e.g.: Tomcat access logs), you don't.

To test this, try to log out the MDC context map inside of the controller method, the MDC context should contain the tracing-related fields.

Comment: That's the thing, that I am inside of the controller method, I am outputting the MDC map and it is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if you are not calling `MDC.clear();` before.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35123552)